# Cannot add source file from different folder using CMake

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-studio-3.0

I am getting an error when I try to add .cpp and .h file in CMake. The header files in the same folder are working.
I working on Android Studio 3.0.
The error is:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (add_library):
Cannot find source file:
libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO.cpp
Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
.hxx .in .txx
```

Path of CMake is:

```
\app\src\main\jni\CMakeLists
```

Path of the .cpp and .h file is:

```
libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO
```

The CMake file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(
        PATH_TO_SUPERPOWERED "libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO"
        CACHE STRING ""
)

message(${ANDROID_ABI})

file(GLOB CPP_FILES
        "*.h"
        "*.cpp")

add_executable(CPPFILES ${CPP_FILES})

add_library(
        libs
        SHARED
        libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO.cpp
)

target_include_directories(libs PRIVATE
        libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO
        )
include_directories(src/main/jni)

include_directories(${PATH_TO_SUPERPOWERED})

target_link_libraries(
        libs
        log
        android
        OpenSLES
        ${PATH_TO_SUPERPOWERED}/libSuperpoweredAndroid.a
)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You said: "path of the .cpp and h is `libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO`" so you should add `libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO.cpp` to your add library call.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the path you use to reference the library source file appears incorrect. You mentioned the library sources are here:

```
libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO
```

So, the full path to the library source file `SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO.cpp` should be:

```
libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO.cpp
```

Even better, use the path you **already** defined in a CMake variable `PATH_TO_SUPERPOWERED` to reference the source file. If it is indeed the same path, save yourself some typing and just reference it using the variable wherever possible:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(
        PATH_TO_SUPERPOWERED "libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO"
        CACHE STRING ""
)

message(${ANDROID_ABI})

file(GLOB CPP_FILES
        "*.h"
        "*.cpp")

add_executable(CPPFILES ${CPP_FILES})

# Reference the source file using the path defined in your CMake variable.
add_library(
        libs
        SHARED
        ${PATH_TO_SUPERPOWERED}/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO.cpp
)

# You can remove this call because it is redundant with 
# the 'include_directories' call below.
target_include_directories(libs PRIVATE
        libs/Superpowered/AndroidIO/SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO
        )

# You can merge the two 'include_directories' calls into one.
include_directories(
    src/main/jni 
    ${PATH_TO_SUPERPOWERED}
)

target_link_libraries(
        libs
        log
        android
        OpenSLES
        ${PATH_TO_SUPERPOWERED}/libSuperpoweredAndroid.a
)
```